# Variable $1 as variable

Tags: bash

How can I set $1 variable as another variable? I want to run something like:

```
$ ./script london
Some output with John in text
```

And the script should be like:

```
#!/bin/bash
london="John"
ukraina="Yury"
romania="Ion"
cat /path/to/file | grep $1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't recommend blindly looking up variable names. A user could pass in any variable, not just one of the three you expect.

Instead, use an associative array.

```
declare -A names=([london]=John [ukraina]=Yury [romania]=Ion)
grep "${names[$1]}" /path/to/file
```

Or if your version of bash doesn't support associative arrays, use a `case` lookup.

```
case $1 in
    london)  name=John;;
    ukraina) name=Yury;;
    romania) name=Ion;;
esac

grep "$name" /path/to/file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
london="Jhon"
ukraina="Yury"
romania="Ion"

cat /path/to/file | grep ${!1}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to declare $1 as variable use this:

```
VARIABLE="$1"
```

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
VARIABLE="$1"
echo $VARIABLE
```